# Is it possible to use an existing ASP.NET Core AuthenticationHandler with ServiceStack?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, servicestack

I have a custom `AuthenticationHandler` built to tie into the Claims-based authorization in ASP.NET Core. Is it possible for ServiceStack to re-use this component, or will I have to implement it as a custom `AuthProvider`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the new [mvcidentity .NET Core template](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcidentity) which shows an example of using ASP.NET identity Auth to protect both MVC and ServiceStack Services.

The [integration is enabled with the new NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcidentity/blob/master/MyApp/Startup.cs#L259) which provides a bidirectional adapter that converts between an ASP.NET Core ClaimsPrincipal and a ServiceStack User Session.